# XBOX Kinect 360 motion capture

Tags: rigging, add-on, motion-capture

A while back I saw a video where the user used XBOX Kinect 360 with Blender 3D to rig and capture facial movement. I'm trying to find that video and how to do that.  All I see are third party people who want money for something that was done in open source.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of https://ni-mate.com/